# Nginx html page still live after deleting it

Tags: nginx

I'm a bit confused now. I've installed nginx server on centOS. After deleting nginx folder from server nginx default html page is still live although the page was located in the deleted folder. How is that possible?

(I restated server after deleting the nginx folder)

Comment: Maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236078/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-nginx

Answer (score 2):

You will need to clear your browser cache as static content caches easily client side.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure you have deleted the binary file, maybe in `/usr/sbin/nginx` or try `locate nginx` because you may have still the binary file and it starts when the system start, also the html file located somewhere in

```
/usr/local/nginx/html
/usr/nginx/html
```

Hope this helps.